# Moving rows between 2 Kendo UI Grids via row command buttons

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My current assignment is to move rows of data between 2 Kendo Ui grids when a user clicks a button in that row. I have code that actually works, but I don't understand why and was hoping someone could explain it. I am also wondering if there is a better approach or one that makes sense to accomplish this task. The environment is Winsows 7, VS2012, MVC4, Kendo UI, jquery 1.8.
The part I don't understand is the moveTo function. The part starting with
    var row = $(elem.currentTarget).closest("tr");
and the whole toDS.add(.... is very confusing. It seems like to me that I'm looping through each cell in the row and adding that to the toDs, but why all the fields? Seems like I should be doing something like what is commented out below that, but that doesn't work.

Other things to note. I have seen http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2qXKy/
but the customer does not want to use selections in the grids, they want to have individual buttons. I have also looked at http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/get-row-id-from-grid-when-custom-command-button-is-clicked.aspx. This is where I got the idea for the commented out section of code.
Can I make this any easier? Thanks

Here is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AmWins.AL.GB.Web.ViewModels.BillingGroupPersonViewModel>

<h2>Add People</h2>
<div id="plan-entry" class="batchEntryContainer">
<div id="availableBillingGroupPeopleGrid"></div>
<div class="clear" />
<br />
<div id="addBillingGroupPeopleGrid"></div>
<div class="clear" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $availableBillingGroupPeopleGrid = $('#availableBillingGroupPeopleGrid').kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            // Match field names to AmWins.AL.GB.Web.ViewModels.BillingGroupPersonViewModel properties
            { command: { text: "push me", click: copySelectedToAddBillingGroupPeopleGrid, class: "action-column" }, title: " ", headerTemplate: '<button type="button" id="moveAllDown">Click Me!</button>', width: 50 },
            { field: "LastNameFirst", title: "Name" },
            { field: "EffectiveDate" },
            { field: "Status" },
            { field: "PersonId", title: "Person ID" },
            { field: "RelationshipType", title: "Type" },
            { field: "SSN" },
            { field: "StreetAddress", title: "Address" },
            { field: "City" },
            { field: "State" },
            { field: "Zip" }
        ],
        editable: false,
        scrollable: false,
        dataSource: {}
    });

    @foreach (var person in Model) {
        <text>
    var $getGrid = $("#availableBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    $getGrid.dataSource.add({
        LastNameFirst: '@person.LastNameFirst',
        EffectiveDate: '@person.EffectiveDate',
        Status: '@person.Status',
        PersonId: '@person.PersonId',
        RelationshipType: '@person.RelationshipType',
        SSN: '@person.SSN',
        StreetAddress: '@person.StreetAddress',
        City: '@person.City',
        State: '@person.State',
        Zip: '@person.Zip'
    });
    </text>
    }

    var $addBillingGroupPeopleGrid = $('#addBillingGroupPeopleGrid').kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            // Match field names to AmWins.AL.GB.Web.ViewModels.BillingGroupPersonViewModel properties
            { command: { text: "push me", click: copySelectedToAvailableBillingGroupPeopleGrid, class: "action-column" }, title: " ", headerTemplate: '<button type="button" id="moveAllUp">Click Me!</button>', width: 50 },
            { field: "LastNameFirst", title: "Name" },
            { field: "EffectiveDate" },
            { field: "Status" },
            { field: "PersonId", title: "Person ID" },
            { field: "RelationshipType", title: "Type" },
            { field: "SSN" },
            { field: "StreetAddress", title: "Address" },
            { field: "City" },
            { field: "State" },
            { field: "Zip" }
        ],
        editable: false,
        scrollable: false,
        dataSource: {},
        loadeddata: onloadeddata
    });

    function copySelectedToAddBillingGroupPeopleGrid(elem)
    {
        moveTo("down", elem);
    }

    function copySelectedToAvailableBillingGroupPeopleGrid(elem)
    {
        moveTo("up", elem);
    }

    function moveTo(direction, elem)
    {
        var fromGrid;
        var fromDS;
        var toDS;

        if(direction == "down")
        {
            fromGrid = $("#availableBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            fromDS = $("#availableBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
            toDS = $("#addBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        }
        else
        {
            fromGrid = $("#addBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            fromDS = $("#addBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
            toDS = $("#availableBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        }
        var row = $(elem.currentTarget).closest("tr");
        row.each(function () {
            var dataItem = fromGrid.dataItem($(this));
            toDS.add(
            {
                LastNameFirst: dataItem.LastNameFirst,
                EffectiveDate: dataItem.EffectiveDate,
                Status: dataItem.Status,
                PersonId: dataItem.PersonId,
                RelationshipType: dataItem.RelationshipType,
                SSN: dataItem.SSN,
                StreetAddress: dataItem.StreetAddress,
                City: dataItem.City,
                State: dataItem.State,
                Zip: dataItem.Zip
            });
        });
        fromGrid.removeRow($(elem.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        // This code only adds the pushbutton in the first column, not the entire row contents.
        //var uid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-uid');
        //var dataRow = fromDS.getByUid(uid);
        //var dataItem = fromGrid.dataItem($(dataRow));
        //toDS.add(dataItem);
    }
    function onloadeddata()
    {
        $("#move-all-up").click(moveAllUp);
        $("#move-all-down").click(moveAllDown);
    }
    function moveAllUp()
    {

    }
    function moveAllDown()
    {
        copySelectedToAddBillingGroupPeopleGrid($(this));
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually finally figured out how to do this. Here was my solution. I realized that the code I had commented out wasn't working because it was below the removeRow call, so there was no longer any data in that table. I also realized that there was an extra statement that wasn't required and wasn't putting any data into the datasource.

```
function copySelectedToAddBillingGroupPeopleGrid(elem)
    {
        moveTo(elem, $("#availableBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid"), $("#addBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid"));
    }
function copySelectedToAvailableBillingGroupPeopleGrid(elem)
    {
        moveTo(elem, $("#addBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid"), $("#availableBillingGroupPeopleGrid").data("kendoGrid"));
    }
function moveTo(elem, fromGrid, toGrid)
    {
        toGrid.dataSource.add(fromGrid.dataSource.getByUid($(elem.currentTarget).closest("tr").attr('data-uid')));
        fromGrid.removeRow($(elem.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    }
```